# PowerBI custom visualisation development

Tags: node.js, typescript, leaflet, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm looking to creating custom visualisation for PowerBI and so far tried a few repos available online. Unfortunately majority of them don't work as intendant or don't work at all. One of the reasons that I could find is the outdate version of Pbiviz API, but even after updating the version (which looks a little dodgy btw) sample apps didn't work.

I'm just interested if anyone know a working example of such app or have any experience in development of PowerBI custom visual plugin. Any recommendations are highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Kindly paste the code in the question section of what you have tried.It would be easy for anyone to help.

Comment: Hi, I have created one and its not possible to paste the whole code here. You can ask in which part you are facing problem. For basic helps please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-custom-visuals-getting-started-with-developer-tools

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find the guide to the new(er) API and dev environment of developing Power BI custom visuals.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-custom-visuals

You can use this tutorial to develop your first viz:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-custom-visuals-getting-started-with-developer-tools

and later to reuse available repos in the gallery or write your own.